# How to display and anchor text with ARCore and OpenGL without Sceneform?

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I want to recreate AR measurement app using ARCore and OpenGL without sceneform. Is there any way to display text and anchor it to another object like the image below?

[image: ARuler]

Comment: Have you found the answer, yet? if yes than please share

Comment: Hello , did you found any answer regarding the mentioned issue? Please do share how you achieved that. @Inas

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can see a preview of it here : [reference](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable) and [example](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/create-renderables).

You can use ViewRenderable Class from AR Core

Answer (score 0):

Your text should be an object like everything that you draw on the screen. Then using sceneform you can place and anchor in reference to another anchor. Check out the solar system example that is provided with sceneform SDK. You have there a perfect example of putting multiple objects in relation each to another and also an example of placing overlays with text.